# How do i make frozen pizza crispy and what temperature is required?

Tags: baking, pizza

I want to know that how i make frozen pizza fresh and crispy.And what temperature of microwave oven is required for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome, Ushna!

You cannot make anything crispy in a microwave.  Microwaves supply wet heat.  You need dry heat, like from an oven or stovetop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microwaves don't make things crispy, and aren't defined by temperature, but by power level. First you need an oven, then a good place to start is following the instructions on the pack, assuming you bought one intended to be crispy. Generally a high temperature is needed